# How to extract public key from a .Net DLL in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, rsa, cryptoapi

I want to extract public key, not public key token, in C# from a autenticode signed .Net DLL?

Comment: did you try [GetPublicKey](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assemblyname.getpublickey%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)?

Comment: Does it need to be via code or would going through the windows GUI be ok?

Comment: using code as I want to do it runtime. I can extract for my use easily.

Comment: @Default I understand that GetPublicKey gets strong name signature not autenticode signature

Comment: I believe Authenticode is actually outside the CLR since it can be used for unmanaged code as well.  Perhaps head down the road investigating the WinTrustVerify function. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa388208%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To get a public key from an Autenticode signed .Net library use the following code:

```
Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom("dll_file_name");
X509Certificate certificate = assembly.ManifestModule.GetSignerCertificate();

byte[] publicKey = certificate.GetPublicKey();
```

But this will work only if the certificate was installed into Trusted Root Certification Authorities. Otherwise, `GetSignerCertificate()` returns null.

The second way allows to get a certificate even if it isn't in Trusted Root Certification Authorities.

```
X509Certificate executingCert = X509Certificate.CreateFromSignedFile("dll_file_name");
byte[] publicKey = certificate.GetPublicKey();
```

Comment: How can you post through a closevote, did you leave the page open for half an hour before submitting? :)

Comment: Yes, the page was opened.

Comment: The original question does not have this answer! Thanks.